# How do you draw a sampler2D?

Tags: glsl, processing

I am new to Glsl and have absolutely no idea what I am doing. I have been looking for resources to learn however, most of them are either incredibly general like [the book of shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/) or really overwhelming like [this reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/).

Anyways, I am looking for what exactly a "fragment" is. I think it is just referring to pixels that need to be rendered. If this is the case what does gl_FragCoord return? I've messed around with it and I don't think it returns the x,y of the current fragment but the book of shaders says

> "vec4 gl_FragCoord, which holds the screen coordinates of the pixel or screen fragment that the active thread is working on."

I have also seen that it returns values from 0 to 1, initially (0.5,0.5). I have no idea what (0.5,0.5) is referring to though. Is it percentage of the screen? Like on a 800px by 800px screen will 0.5,0.5 correspond to 400,400? If so than why doesn't this sort of thing work:

```
void main() {
  vec4 screencol = texture2D(displayimg, gl_FragCoord.xy*vec2(width,height));
  gl_FragColor = screencol;
}
```

Where width and height store the screen dimensions and displayimg is a sampler2D.

I am just trying to render a sampler2D and I must be missing something because this seems like something that should be very standard and achievable. With the above code I get an error:

```
OpenGL error 1282 at top endDraw(): invalid operation
```

Thanks for your help.

ps this is probably incredibly cringey for you master glsl people, sry

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, I have read that over many times, but what does it mean? It says it returns between 0 and 1. Is that saying (0.0,0.0) means (0,0) and (1.0,1.0) means (width,height)?

Comment: `Anyways, I am looking for what exactly a "fragment" is.  I think it is just referring to pixels that need to be rendered.` One pixel of an output image is composed out of 0-N fragments. There can be 0-N fragments for one pixel because you can have overlapping triangles that might need to be blended. But yes a fragment refers to a pixel.

Comment: @DanielMorgan Read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gl_FragCoord.xy` contains the window relative coordinates. The bottom left fragment has the coordinate (*0.5*, *0.5*). The top right fragment has the coordinate (*width-0.5*, *height-0.5*). See [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml).
However the texture coordinates have to be specified in range [0.0, 1.0].  The bottom left coordinate is (0.0, 0.0). The top right coordinate is (1.0, 1.0). The argument of [`texture2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml) needs to be the texture cooridante:

<s>`vec4 screencol = texture2D(displayimg, gl_FragCoord.xy*vec2(width,height));`</s>

```c
vec4 screencol = texture2D(displayimg, gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(width, height));
```